# Dynamic formula help in Excel

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula, conditional-statements

Hi I am looking to use the following formula to determine if a numerical output for an indicator (`O2`) meets a particular target (`Q2`):

```
=IF(O2<>"",IF(O2>=Q2,"Met","Not Met"),"").
```

However, included within columns O & Q are different indicators and their corresponding targets, some targets are defined as met if above their target and some if below. Hence, the >= section of my formula above should be dynamic. Is there any way to reference a cell which will include either < or >= in the above formula to change the formula according to how the target should analysed?

An excerpt of my data:

[image: An excerpt of my data]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIF` function:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2,C2&D2),"Met","Not met")
```

[image]